# Cocoa touch dimming background darker

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

Hey! I am making an app with a slider which slides out from the bottom and I would like to make other parts of the app a bit darker to show that the picker is the active component, like when alertbox comes, the background darkens. How do archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlay the elements you want to darken with a view that has a semi-transparent dark background (e.g. a black background with an alpha value of 0.5).

Comment: Is there possible way to make the view fade in slowly and thanks for reply!

Comment: Sure, just the standard UIView animations. The documentation has all the details.